# What does "golden thread" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> Our **golden thread** is always to streamline our processes and to continuously raise the bar for ourselves in everything we do.

I cannot find an appropriate explanation for "golden thread" in the dictionary. Is "golden thread" similar to "recipe for success"?

And is it an idiomatic expression or made-up phrase?

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/golden-thread - it's definitely not made up, but not used often in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to be a variation on "golden rule":

> **[golden rule](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/golden%20rule)** (n): 2. A guiding principle

Using "thread" rather than "rule" implies that it is something that *threads* throughout the organization, rather than something imposed as an overarching principle.

> **[thread](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thread)** (v): 2b. to make one's way through or between

It's a matter of opinion whether there is any difference in meaning between "thread" and "rule", but it it does create a different metaphorical image.

Comment: The latter (thread) is likely to be more accurate given one given https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/golden-thread where it is defined as "an idea or feature that is present in all parts of something, **holds it together** and gives it value" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic phrase "the golden thread" refers to a pervasive idea or basic principle.

See [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/golden-thread).

> an idea or feature that is present in all parts of something, holds it together and gives it value